# Jquery create, trigger en listen to event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I've a timeline which can load content over ajax or you can just add content directly to the element.

When you load over ajax; an event is triggered.

```
/* trigger */
var event = jQuery.Event( 'ajaxLoaded.timeline' );
event.element = $newThis.find('.item_open_content');
$( "body" ).trigger( event );
$this.trigger(event);
```

When I initialise the timeline; the timeline 'listen' to the event and generate a scrollbar if necessary

```
$('.tl1').on('ajaxLoaded.timeline', function(e){
    var height = e.element.height()-60-e.element.find('h2').height();
    e.element.find('.timeline_open_content span').css('max-height', height).mCustomScrollbar({ 
        autoHideScrollbar:true,
        theme:"light-thin"
    }); 
});
```

In this example the first timeline: http://karlienfabre.be/bas-cms/timeline-test/

Now I building the timeline with bolt cms, so instead of an ajaxload I just put the content directly in the element (second timeline). So I trigger an event:

```
var event = jQuery.Event( 'sItemOpen.timeline' );
event.element = $newThis.find('.item_open_content');
$( "body" ).trigger( event );
$this.trigger(event);
```

The I let the timeline listen to it.

```
$('.tl2').on('sItemOpen.timeline', function(e){
    console.log(e.element.find('.timeline_open_content span'));

    var height = e.element.height()-60-e.element.find('h2').height();
    e.element.find('.timeline_open_content span').css('max-height', height).mCustomScrollbar({
        autoHideScrollbar:true,
        theme:"light-thin"
    }); 
});
```

But that's not working... I event can't get into the last piece of code if I try a console.log there.

The timeline js: http://bas-cms.dev/timeline-test/js/jquery.timeline.js

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You only must do need a show mCustomScrollbar if necessary, you should solve this problem only use to css. You set element max-height properties. If your content height bigger than your max-height properties, its displaying automaticaly.

If your problem is jQuery create event and listening? You use code below.

you set any variable..

```
$.event.trigger('shared', [1, 'Linkedin share', false, target]);

$(document).bind('shared', function(e,type,desc,res,tar){
     if(typeof res !== 'undefined'){
         console.log(type,desc,res,tar);           
     }
     return false;
});
```